# How to add autoplay (automove/autoslide) to csslider?

Tags: css, animation, slider

Anyones knows how to add autoplay to this slider? I want this slider to start moving automatically when it's visible on screen

is it possible? Thanks

Code here: https://codepen.io/casimirp/pen/kHcub

```
<div class="csslider">
<input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_1" checked />
<input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_2" />
<input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_3" />
<input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_4" />
<input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_5" />
<ul>
    <li><p>Content of slide 1</p>
    <p>Content of slide 1</p>
    <p>Content of slide 1</p>
    <p>Content of slide 1</p>
    <p>Content of slide 1</p>
    <p>Content of slide 1</p>
    <p>Content of slide 1</p>
    </li>
    <li>Content of slide 2</li>
    <li>Content of slide 3</li>
    <li>Content of slide 4</li>
    <li>Content of slide 5</li>
</ul>
<div class="arrows">
    <label for="slides_1"></label>
    <label for="slides_2"></label>
    <label for="slides_3"></label>
    <label for="slides_4"></label>
    <label for="slides_5"></label>
</div>
<div class="navigation">
    <div>
        <label for="slides_1"></label>
        <label for="slides_2"></label>
        <label for="slides_3"></label>
        <label for="slides_4"></label>
        <label for="slides_5"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with simple **JQuery** with Interval

Or Use [Bootstrap JS Carousel](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_carousel2&stacked=h)

```js
setInterval(function(){
  if($('input[name="slides"]:checked').next('input[name="slides"]')[0])
    $('input[name="slides"]:checked').next('input[name="slides"]')[0].checked = true
  else
    $('input[name="slides"]')[0].checked = true
},2000)
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700|Lato);

body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  font: 400 100% 'Raleway', 'Lato';
}

.csslider {
  /*important*/
  margin: 22px;
  /*important*/
  -moz-perspective: 1300px;
  -ms-perspective: 1300px;
  -webkit-perspective: 1300px;
  perspective: 1300px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.csslider > input {
  display: none;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type( 5):checked ~ ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -400%;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type( 4):checked ~ ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -300%;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type( 3):checked ~ ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -200%;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type( 2):checked ~ ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -100%;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type( 1):checked ~ ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0%;
}
.csslider > ul {
  /*important*/
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  /*important*/
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.csslider > ul > li {
  /*important*/
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: initial;
  font-size: 15px;
  /*important*/
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: normal;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.5, 1, 0.5, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.5, 1, 0.5, 1);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.5, 1, 0.5, 1);
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: normal;
}
/*-------------NAVIGATION-------------*/
.csslider > .navigation {
  position: absolute;
  /*important*/
  bottom: -8px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  /*important*/
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.csslider > .navigation > div {
  margin-left: -100%;
}
.csslider > .navigation label {
  /*important*/
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  background: #909090;
  /*important*/
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.csslider > .navigation label:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.csslider > .navigation label:after {
  /*important*/
  margin-left: -6px;
  margin-top: -6px;
  padding: 6px;
  background: #000000;
  border-radius: 50%;  
  /*important*/
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
}
 
.csslider.inside .navigation {
  bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(1):after,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(2):after,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(3):after,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(4):after,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(5):after
{
  opacity: 1;
}
/*-------------ARRROWS-------------*/
.csslider > .arrows {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.csslider > .arrows {
  /*important*/
  left: -31px;
  padding: 0 31px;
  height: 26px;
  /*important*/
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.csslider > .arrows label {
  /*important*/
  box-shadow: inset 2px -2px 0 1px #909090;
  /*important*/
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.15s, margin 0.15s;
  -o-transition: box-shadow 0.15s, margin 0.15s;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.15s, margin 0.15s;
  transition: box-shadow 0.15s, margin 0.15s;
}
.csslider > .arrows label:hover {
  /*important*/
  box-shadow: inset 3px -3px 0 2px #000000;
  /*important*/
  margin: 0 0px;
}
.csslider.infinity > input:first-of-type:checked ~ .arrows label.goto-last,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(0),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(1),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(2),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(3),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(4)
{
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.csslider.infinity > input:last-of-type:checked ~ .arrows label.goto-first,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(2),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(3),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(4),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(5)
{
  display: block;
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);  
  -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="csslider">
<input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_1" checked />
<input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_2" />
<input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_3" />
<input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_4" />
<input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_5" />
<ul>
    <li><p>Content of slide 1</p>
    <p>Content of slide 1</p>
    <p>Content of slide 1</p>
    <p>Content of slide 1</p>
    <p>Content of slide 1</p>
    <p>Content of slide 1</p>
    <p>Content of slide 1</p>
    </li>
    <li>Content of slide 2</li>
    <li>Content of slide 3</li>
    <li>Content of slide 4</li>
    <li>Content of slide 5</li>
</ul>
<div class="arrows">
    <label for="slides_1"></label>
    <label for="slides_2"></label>
    <label for="slides_3"></label>
    <label for="slides_4"></label>
    <label for="slides_5"></label>
</div>
<div class="navigation">
    <div>
        <label for="slides_1"></label>
        <label for="slides_2"></label>
        <label for="slides_3"></label>
        <label for="slides_4"></label>
        <label for="slides_5"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```